# Recommended way to batch stdin lines to another repeated command, like xargs but via stdin rather than arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, xargs, gnu-coreutils

I've got a data-import script that reads lines and adds them to a database, so far so good. Unfortunately something in the script (or its runtime or database library or whatever) is memory leaky, so large imports use monotonically increasing main memory, leading to slow swap and then memory-exhausted process death. Breaking the import up into multiple runs is a workaround; I've been doing that with `split` then doing a looped execution of the import script on each piece.

But I'd rather skip making the split files and this feels like it should be a 1-liner. In fact, it seems there should be an equivalent to `xargs` that passes the lines through to the specified command on stdin, instead of as arguments. If this hypothetical command were `xlines`, then I'd expect the following to run the `myimport` script for each batch of up-to 50,000 lines in giantfile.txt:

```
cat giantfile.txt | xlines -L 50000 myimport
```

Am I missing an `xlines`-like capability under some other name, or hidden in some other command's options? Or can `xlines` be done in a few lines of BASH script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use GNU Parallel - available [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

You will need the `--pipe` option and also the `--block` option (which takes a byte size, rather than a line count).

Something along the lines of:

```
cat giantfile.txt | parallel -j 8 --pipe --block 4000000 myimport
```

(That's choosing a blocksize of 50,000 lines * 80 bytes = 4000000, which could also be abbreviated `4m` here.)

If you don't want the jobs to actually run in parallel, change the `8` to `1`. Or, you can leave it out altogether and it will run one job per CPU core.

You can also avoid the `cat`, by running

```
parallel ... < giantfile.txt
```

Comment: Aha! I suspected a form of `parallel` might be involved but missed that `-pipe` was just the right thing. Thanks!

Comment: In my tests (including with most recent gnu parallel source), the `-L` option doesn't work with `--pipe` (which does require double-dashes). You have to use `--block` instead, which specifies the batch size in raw bytes. (`parallel` automatically pushes fragmented records into the next block). Answer updated.

Comment: Ok, my apologies for the inaccuracies. Thank you for correcting the answer for the rest of the community. Maybe @OleTange (author of GNU Parallel) will take a look to ensure we are all correct now.

Comment: --pipe -L gives the record size in lines. What you want is --pipe -N (number of records - a record defaults to 1 line). But --block is more efficient (around 100 MB/s). And --pipepart (from version 20140622) more efficient still (around 3 GB/s).

Answer (score 1):

My approach, without installing `parallel`, and without writing temporary files:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ ! -f "$1" ] && echo "missing file." && exit 1

command="$(which cat)" # just as example, insert your command here
totalSize="$(wc -l $1 | cut -f 1 -d ' ')"
chunkSize=3 # just for the demo, set to 50000 in your version
offset=1

while [ $[ $totalSize + 1 ] -gt $offset ]; do

        tail -n +$offset $1 | head -n $chunkSize | $command
        let "offset = $offset + $chunkSize"
        echo "----"
done
```

Test:

```
seq 1000 1010 > testfile.txt
./splitter.sh testfile.txt
```

Output:

```
1000
1001
1002
----
1003
1004
1005
----
1006
1007
1008
----
1009
1010
----
```

This way, the solution remains portable, and the performance is better than with temporary files.

Comment: For curiousity's sake, I am interested in learning the optimal/idiomatic bash-script-based way to do this... your approach seems a step in that direction, but the repeated scanning of the file (for initial `wc` and each `head`/`tail` slice) involves a lot of redundant IO in the mega-sized-file case. (As I mention in another comment on another answer, I think bash built-in `mapfile` or named-pipes might be part of the ideal bash-based answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Save following code as a test.sh script.

```
 #!/bin/bash
tempFile=/tmp/yourtempfile.temp
rm -f tempFile > /dev/null 2>&1
declare -i cnt=0
while read line
do
    cnt=$(($cnt+1))
    if [[ $cnt < $1 || $cnt == $1 ]]; then
            echo $line >> tempFile
    else
        echo $line >> tempFile
        cat tempFile | myimport
        rm -f tempFile > /dev/null 2>&1
        cnt=$((0))
    fi
done < $2

exit 0
```

Then run `./test.sh 500000 giantfile.txt`. 
I use a tempFile to save specified number of lines, then use your import script dealing with it. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! But I still need to use large batches of many thousands of lines per run – each run involves enough overhead (in particular a database-connection and transaction) that a run-per-line is very slow.

Comment: Thanks for the update; this use of a single tempfile at a time would be an improvement over the preemptive `split`, if the `parallel`-based approach wasn't usable. I suppose that if the chunk sizes are guaranteed to fit in memory, the temp file could be skipped and an in-memory array, for example as from the bash builtin `mapfile`, could be used. And probably there's a way to skip the explicit temp file by using named pipes, too...